# 433 Receiver Arduino if statement

Tags: c++, arduino

433 MHz receiver

Arduino environment

The transmitter sends **Y**, **N** or **M** which works just fine. The problem lies in the receivers code. The goal is, after the receiver has value **message** equal N, its suppose to trigger an if statement which would do a thing. I simply need to have a system that can determine if the receiver takes in a specific value.

```
void loop()
{
    if (vw_get_message(message, &messageLength)) // Non-blocking
    {
        Serial.print("Received: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < messageLength; i++)
        {
            Serial.write(message[i]);
            const char *p = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(message);
            if(p == "N")
            {
                Serial.print("if statement works when = N");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem, is it simply does not do the job, and after 2 weeks of struggle, I am completely at a loss. This code will compile and run, but the if statement is completely ignored.

Comment: You're comparing a `char` to a `string`. The quotes make a difference in C++. Check that.

Comment: Here, `p` is a pointer to a variable while `"N"` is a pointer to a constant. So it's almost impossible for their values to be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully I was able to find a solution.

The working code:

```
void loop()
{
        if (vw_get_message(message, &messageLength))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < messageLength; i++)
        {
             const char *p = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(message);
             if(p[0] == 'Y')
             {
                  Serial.print(" - Yes");
                  break;
             }
             else if(p[0] == 'N')
             {
                  Serial.print(" - No");
                  break;
             }
        }
        Serial.println();
    }
}
```

The point of `const char *p = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(message);` was to turn `message`, which is a byte, into a char. Yes `p` is a pointer, but it's pointing to a char, so with that, I can get the data in the char that `p` is pointing to by simply doing **p[#]**. A simple if statement can now be made

```
if(p[0] == 'M')
{
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`if (p=="N")` compares two pointers. While the contents they point to can be identical, that does not mean the pointers themselves are equal.

You may want `strcmp` (C style) or `std::string::operator==` (canonical C++)

Answer (score -1):

What type is `message`? Anyway, right now you are comparing value stored in `p` (so the address in memory, not what there is) to a string (notice double quotes). Why don't you just do

```
if(message[i] == 'N')
```

Single quotes here mean char literal.